# AAD AppRoles allowedMemberTypes for both application and user

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, manifest

According to [Add app roles in your application and receive them in the token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps), I can create an `AppRole` for users, applications or both.

If I want to target users, the property `allowedMemberTypes` on the **Manifest** should be `User`. For applications, `Application`, but what about both?

What is the `allowedMemberTypes` for both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`allowedMemberTypes` is an array, so you can put in both "User" & "Application":

```js
"appRoles": [
  {
    "allowedMemberTypes": [
      "User", "Application"
    ],
    "displayName": "Writer",
    "id": "d1c2ade8-98f8-45fd-aa4a-6d06b947c66f",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "description": "Writers Have the ability to create tasks.",
    "value": "Writer"
  }
],
```

Comment: Ops, I didnt pay attention on the array. Thanks!

Comment: Is it working for you? I use both `User` and `Application` and `Delegated permission`is still disabled.